# Overides attachment shows current only

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

This only show the current attachment in the repeater i want it to show old also

```
  SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

            SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(DropDownListSelectCategory.SelectedItem.Value);


            HyperLink hp = new HyperLink();
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {

                SPListItemCollection oListItems = list.Items;
                foreach (SPListItem item in oListItems)
                {
                    SPAttachmentCollection collAttachments = item.Attachments;




                    foreach (var attachment in collAttachments)
                    {

                        hp.NavigateUrl = collAttachments.UrlPrefix + attachment;

                        hp.Text = collAttachments.UrlPrefix + attachment;
                        hp.ID = e.Item.ItemIndex.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
                    }



                }
            }
            e.Item.Controls.Add(hp); 
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean? The attachments does not support versions.

Comment: when uploading attachment to list i want it to show it in the repeater , the first uploaded attachments show up. When uploading second attachment it overrides the first attachment and show the second attachment in repeater so i get the newest attachment in first and second, but i want to show only every singel attachment that i upload so if i upload 10 attachment i want it to display all the attachment in the repeater

Comment: Have you added the same file as secondary attachment?

Comment: no i have not....

Comment: Please could you edit your question with that additional information? - it will help people using the site in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create Hyperlink column inside attachment loop and add it in control collection like this:

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(DropDownListSelectCategory.SelectedItem.Value);
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
{
    SPListItemCollection oListItems = list.Items;
    foreach (SPListItem item in oListItems)
    {       
        SPAttachmentCollection collAttachments = item.Attachments;
        foreach (var attachment in collAttachments)
        {
            HyperLink hp = new HyperLink();
            hp.NavigateUrl = collAttachments.UrlPrefix + attachment;
            hp.Text = collAttachments.UrlPrefix + attachment;
            hp.ID = e.Item.ItemIndex.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
            e.Item.Controls.Add(hp); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl to combine urls

Comment: Nadeem YouSuf Not it show both attachment in i only want it to show one attachmen for every splistitem that i upload. 
//Example
//Name:Simon
//Age:25
//Attachment: hello.jpg

//Name:Arnold
//Age:25
//Attachment:jebiga.jpg

Comment: In that case, as Alexander mentioned above, Attachments do not support versions. You can have many attachments, but only 1 version each.

Comment: okej , so how should i do? I want to upload a image to splist and then display it in a repeater?

Comment: When we are only using this code: <a href="<%# ((SPListItem)Container.DataItem).Attachments.UrlPrefix %>" target="_blank"><%# ((SPListItem)Container.DataItem).Attachments[0] %> it picks right attachment, but the url doesn't change. It's the url to the attachmentcollection, not to the attachment itself

Comment: You can use Document Library instead of list. Document library supports versions, also you can add any meta information, all that you need is to add needed columns.

Comment: oki and how should make that the image belongs to specified listitem?

Comment: the element of document library is a file with meta info. In your case it's an image. You can create you own content type based on picture library content type with needed columns. Also do not forget to use @ before my name, in other case I do not receive notifications.